# Blade not displaying model values from the database

Tags: foreach, eloquent, forms-authentication, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

I am trying to display the list of products for a user, and to my surprise this does not display it on the page, though, it is inserted into the database, what could be wrong?

```
public function index()
        {
            $listProducts = Product::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('productname', 'desc');
            return view('product.index')
            ->with('products', $listProducts);
        }
```

Blade file:

```
@if(Auth::check())
                        @foreach($products as $product)

                                <TR><TD>{!! $product->companyname !!}</TD><TD>{!! $product->productname !!}</TR>

                        @endforeach
                    @endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you need to return the data in an array:

```
return view('product.index', ['products' => $listProducts]);
```

As well as changing this:

```
$listProducts = Product::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('productname', 'desc');
```

To this:

```
 $listProducts = Product::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('productname', 'desc')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks. I have added it in this format, it does not display it as well. I wonder why

Comment: do you have "product.index" in the /resources/views/product/index.blade.php file?

Comment: Yes. exactly where it is.

Comment: I'm running it locally.

Comment: When i changed it to Product::all(); it returned all products, disregarding the user context that I only want to make display to the user the product inputted by him or her.

Comment: Change this: `$listProducts = Product::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('productname', 'desc');` to this: `$listProducts = Product::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('productname', 'desc')->get();`

Comment: No problem :-) I love my laravel. Consider upgrading to Laravel 5.2 with PHP 7.0.1 :-)

Comment: Laravel is the only framework that is highly fast evolving. Keep the good work going. Appreciate. I wish to pioneer the use of Laravel in this part of the world.